# Round Down Decimal Places Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need a rounding down many many decimal places down, basically roundTo but supposedly rounding down at the spot. Example,

```
take the number, 1.087179939485353505
but to the fifth place, with roundTo of 6
roundTo(1.087179939485353505, 6) is 1.08718
```

I need 1.08717 not 1.08718 in javascript.

```
var Variable = roundTo(Variable / 1000000000000000000, 6);
```

**Resolved**
There seems to be no native javascript decimal rounding function that rounds down. One of two options are available.

1. Convert to string and manipulate the data that way (makes the most sense).
2. Utilize a number and multiply, floor then re-divide again for your number

Comment: It looks like you want to truncate, not round.

Comment: Truncate does seem the way to go, the answers below have given excellent detail on converting to string and working with it as a string which makes more sense than my answer of using numbers, since for my particular case, I needed a string in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about convert to string, slice and convert back to number.

```js
const roundTo = num => Number(String(num).slice(0, 7));

console.log(roundTo(1.087179939485353505));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex to get 5 decimals

```js
function roundTo(number) {
    var result= number.toString().match(/^\d+(\.\d{0,5})/)[0];
    console.log(result);
}

roundTo(1.087179939485353505);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Variable = Variable / 1000000000000000000;
Variable *= 1000000;
Variable = Math.floor(Variable);
Variable /= 1000000;
var Variable = roundTo(Variable, 6);
```

I took my decimal, multiplied it by how many places I wanted to roundTo, math floor for absolute low rounding and divided it once again before lastly using roundTo for the precise decimal place. Seems the only way.